# attempt to invoke interface method java.lang.string com.facebook.react.bridge.readablemap.get string on a null object reference

Tags: php, react-native

[image]

I am creating signup page in react native.I wanted to generate  random otp.  And opt will send to  user who is performing sign up process. For sending i am using msg91 gatway. But i am having error displayed above..
signupUser function in called over submit button click which will call php api to call msg91 gateway. i m new for react native as well msg91/
please draw me to the issue with my code
and below is my code:

```
 export const signUpUser = ({ name,  password, mobile }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {

    console.log('signupaction');
      //Multiple mobiles numbers separated by comma
        mobileNumber = mobile;
        console.log('signupaction'+mobile);
    var url = "http://congenitalart.com/test/process.php";

    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/text',
            'Content-Type': 'application/text',
        },
        data: mobileNumber

    })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(data){
      console.log(data); //this will just be text
      var data_obj = JSON.parse(data);
      return data_obj
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
      throw error;
      });

  };
};
```

process.php

```
   <?php
    //session_start();
     echo'test process';

        //Your authentication key
        $authKey = '190301AU2RL0SzSK5a460060';
        //Multiple mobiles numbers separated by comma
        $mobileNumber = $_POST["data"];
        echo($mobileNumber);
        //Sender ID,While using route4 sender id should be 6 characters long.
        $senderId = "MSGIND";
        //Your message to send, Add URL encoding here.
        $rndno=rand(1000, 9999);
        $message = urlencode("your OTP for registering with theatrebay.com is".$rndno);
        //Define route 
        $route = "SendOTP";
        //Prepare you post parameters
        $postData = array(
        'authkey' => $authKey,
        'mobiles' => $mobileNumber,
        'message' => $message,
        'sender' => $senderId,
        'route' => $route
        );
        //API URL
        $url="https://control.msg91.com/api/sendhttp.php";
        // init the resource
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData
        //,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
        ));
        //Ignore SSL certificate verification
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        //get response
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        //Print error if any
        if(curl_errno($ch))
        {
            echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {

            $_SESSION['date']=$_POST['date'];
            $_SESSION['tickettype']=$_POST['tickettype'];
            $_SESSION['ticketcount']=$_POST['ticketcount'];
            $_SESSION['name']=$_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['email']=$_POST['emailid'];
            $_SESSION['phone']=$_POST['mobileno'];
            $_SESSION['password']=$_POST['password'];
            $_SESSION['otp']=$rndno;
            $_SESSION['isSold'] = $_POST['cod'];
            $_SESSION['booking'] = "booking";
            header( "Location: otp.php" ); 
        } 
      }
    }

        return 0;
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)